# How to prepend the Image or Icon to h3 tag of JQuery Accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to prepend the Image/Icon to the 'h3' tag of JQuery Accordian
[image]

My Accordians are as follows;

```
    $("#AnalysisAccordian").accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
   });
    $("#AttachmentsAccordian").accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
     $("#AftermarketAccordian").accordion({
       active: false,
       collapsible: true
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily done by using css style like this:

```
  h3:after {
        content: '\27A1'; /* Unicode character for sign (->) */
        font-size: 30px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 5px;  
    }
```

Comment: Can we have some image instead of content(Unicode Character) ?

Comment: update it with  { content: ''; 
    background: url("https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/maps_64dp.png") no-repeat;
     background-size:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;}